# Not able to make Resque work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm trying to make Resque work with my project, but unfortunately it seems that for some reasons Resque is not able to write on Redis.

Redis seems to be configured correctly, I'm able to connect with redis-cli and issue commands, runs on port 6379 as configured inside my Rails 3.0.5 app.
When I try to Resque enqueue something the job is queued, but it doesn't seem that something actually happens on Redis (0 clients connected inside my Redis logs).
When I restart the console, the queue is empty, with no workers running.

Everything fails silently, I have nothing in my rails logs, nothing on the console, nothing if I start a worker, it just (obviously) doesn't find any job to perform.

https://gist.github.com/867620

Any suggestions on how to fix or debug this ?

Comment: Are you starting a worker at all? I mean have you done rake resque:work QUEUE=* ?

Comment: Yes I did. Keeps running and running and does nothing. Anyway, if I Resque.info I see there's nothing in the queue.

Comment: I can't tell. I suspect that because your job is to puts a string the job gets done so fast that you can't see really any job in the queue..But that's only assumptions..Have you installed the sinatra app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that I was including resque_spec in the bundle.
Obviously, resque_spec was stubbing Resque.enqueue, making my mistake very stupid and very difficult to spot.

Comment: Resque_spec sucks so hard!!! Takes me the whole afternoon debugging... (and it gives no explanation when spec fails!!! Garbage!!!)

Comment: Thank a lot for your question and answer! I had exactly the same problem, was debugging all day, tried everything! :( Wish I searched earlier.